# How to populate my model with async/await syntax?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I read many similar posts,mostly examples are with callbacks. I am trying to create a comment and add it to my Post.

```
const Post = require('./models/Post');
const Comment = require('./models/Comment');

const newLocal = 'mongodb://localhost/postdb';
mongoose.connect(newLocal, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  }).then(() => console.log('Successfully connect to MongoDB.'))
  .catch((err) => console.error('Connection error', err));

  async function readP() {
    try {
      const comment = await Comment.create(
        {title : 'Boa tarde', 
        body: 'Adriana bonita',
        postedBy : mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5f96e440f47c1d211e84d712")
      });
       const post = await Post.findOne({ title: 'BJohnson'}).
       populate( {path : 'comment'},
       );
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
  }

  readP();
```

PostSchema

```
const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  body: String,
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
  postedBy: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
  },
  comments: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Comment',
  }] 
});
```

BJohnson post

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5fa13e1523e71045227bf74d"), "comments" : [ ObjectId("5fa13e1523e71045227bf74c") ]
```

Comment was created but it was not added to Post. How to specify  path in a proper manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `findOneAndUpdate()`. In your case it will find the Post and update the Post with commentId.
I'm assuming your Post Schema looks somewhat similar to this -

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  body: String,
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
  postedBy: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
  },
  comments: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Comment',
  }]
});

module.exports = PostSchema
```

```js
const Post = require('./models/Post');
const Comment = require('./models/Comment');

const newLocal = 'mongodb://localhost/postdb';
mongoose.connect(newLocal, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  }).then(() => console.log('Successfully connect to MongoDB.'))
  .catch((err) => console.error('Connection error', err));

  async function readP() {
    try {
      const comment = await Comment.create(
        {title : 'Boa tarde',
        body: 'Adriana bonita',
        postedBy : mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5f96e440f47c1d211e84d712")
      });
      const post = await Post.findOne({ title: 'BJohnson'})

      const commentIds = post.comments || [] // get all the comment Id's of the post
      commentIds.push(comment.id) // Push the new comment id to existing comment Id's
      
      const updatedPost = await Post.findOneAndUpdate({ title: 'BJohnson'}, {comments: commentIds}).populate({path : 'comment'});
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
  }

  readP();
```

Comment: Take a look at my schema.

Comment: Right, as comments is an array. So First we have to get all the comments and then push the new comment Id to it and then use `findOneAndUpdate`. I've updated my code. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Only Id,no title ,no body.

Comment: I didn't understand what you said above.